# How to get the full name of a choice in django-model-utils

Tags: python, django

I am using `django-model-utils` for selecting a choice when adding new entry to the database.
My models look like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   STATUS = Choices(
       ('available', _('Available to borrow')),
       ('borrowed', _('Borrowed by someone')),
   )
   status = models.CharField(
       max_length=32,
       choices=STATUS,
       default=STATUS.available,
   )
```

In my admin page its showing the full name of a choice (Available to borrow), but when I am trying to get this name to the HTML template using `{{ book.status }}`, I get the `available` instead of `Available to borrow`. I have tried `{{ book.status.display_text }}`, but it didn't work. Any idea, hot to pull up the display_text to the HTML template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Model.get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) function as documented

> For every field that has choices set, the object will have a
> get_FOO_display() method, where FOO is the name of the field. This
> method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.

```
{{ book.get_status_display}}
```

Comment: thanks {{ book.get_status_display }} works